# How to spin an image in android?

Tags: android, imageview

I have an image. i want it to spin/flip 360 degree continuously. All the tutorials i m referring are of rotating image 360 on a 2D axis.

I tried using the rotate animation from android but it has same problem of rotating around a point but not 3D spin or flip.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

What you are describing sounds very similar to a [card flip (google android documentation)](http://developer.android.com/training/animation/cardflip.html). Bare in mind that you need to think about what is on the opposite side of the image (for your specific use case) if you are going to implement that.

Comment: I saw that ... that is why i need a full spin coz i don't have back side. It just rotates.

Comment: full spin or not you still need something to display on the "back" side while the view is spinning.

Comment: I think i found a way ... http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/software-engineer/pro-tip-use-androids-objectanimator-class-to-flip-a-view/